# Can players join mid-game?

Tags: storium

In [Storium](https://storium.com/) a narrator can only start his first scene once at least one player has had their submitted character approved. However, it is not clear if once the scene and story has started if other players can join.

It is quite obvious that any player with a pending character approval will join once their characters are approved.

The question is if new players can be invited after the first scene has started? And if new players can submit more characters via the open invitations method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**

Players may submit characters through the open invitations method (as long as you leave it open) and you may also directly invite other players to join via email or using their Storium user name.

Source: The Creator of Storium, Stephen Hood on the [Storium Kickstarter Comments](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/stlhood/storium-the-online-storytelling-game/comments?cursor=6746570#comment-6746569)

> Regarding joining games, yes: you can invite new players and they can join your game at any time, including after the game has started.